# Is it possible to sync specific router settings across multiple routers?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, mac-address

I recently purchased a second Linksys wireless routers set up on the other side of my home and I am wondering if it is possible to somehow sync particular settings between the two?

For instance what I am really after is the "MAC Filter List".  I would "like" to be able to maintain the list on both routers without having to manually type in the field values.

maybe this isn't possible, or has an easy answer, but hopefully those of you who know will cut me a bit of slack.  I tried to "google" the answer to this of course, but it seems any searches with the words "sync" and "router" and/or "wifi" result in pages of people having issues with synching their iOS devices over wifi.

I would say that have decent amount of networking knowledge in regards to average home networks, and I imagine in larger businesses / corporations they must have a "simpler" way of maintaining things like this.

Any insight to point me in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: In Larger businesses / corporations, they also pay big bucks for the ability to have the simpler way of maintaining things. I don't think you'll be able to do what you want in a simple way on home networking hardware.

Comment: I agree fully, I'm just trying to figure out what is involved or how those are set up.  Figure perhaps this is something DD-WRT may be able to help with, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no universal standard for doing this on consumer routers.

You would have to write a script that logs into the web interface of the router and applies the changes you want done.  It's possible, and maybe someone out there has done it, but not trivial.

If the two units are the same make and model, you might be able to download the settings on one unit and upload it to the second unit.  Writing a script to do this might be a little easier.

If you can flash both units to DD-WRT you may be able to perform configuration changes via telnet or SSH.  Telnet/SSH is easily scriptable.

Filtering by MAC doesn't really add much security anyway.  Anyone who you would like to keep out using this will likely be smart enough to pick up a valid MAC address from monitoring traffic, which is entirely possible even if all your traffic is encrypted and MAC filtering is set up.

Comment: thanks @ultrasawblade I know its not bulletproof, but I figure between not broadcasting the ssids, mac filtering, and other security settings that it might just be enough to be a pain in the ass, and they'll move on to the other 100 people in the neighborhood that probably still have the default admin log/pass set that their router shipped with.  Or of course, maybe it makes me a better target for the challenge ;-)

Comment: "Telnet/SSH is easily scriptable" didnt even think of this, thanks for your reply, gave me plenty to start with.

Comment: @BetardFooser It's not a pain in the ass at all for someone that's trying to use the network. The tools used for that stuff require you do *additional* work to *hide* the "hidden" SSIDs, and it takes just a few seconds to grab valid MAC addresses assuming another device is using the WiFi. Just set up WPA2 with AES (not TKIP) and a strong password, and that's all you need to worry about.